# Why was this flagged 'Your question appears to be spam.' as a new user?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, spam, quality-filter

I attempted to post the following question using an account I created for work and it wouldn't let me, giving me the red message:

> Your question appears to be spam.

[Can I add a custom soap authentication header using .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363859/can-i-add-a-custom-soap-authentication-header-using-net-core)

I was able to post it on my home account, I'm guessing because I have enough reputation. I'm baffled at why it was flagged as spam though.

Comment: The question filters work in mysterious ways some times. One way is to try and dissect the message by removing and keeping different chunks until you narrow down what triggers a filter. False positives happen

Comment: No clue, but can't say I'm surprised that a post with 13 URLs in it and almost a quarter of the lines have a URL triggers the spam filter.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's it...  I hadn't even thought of those urls since they are in the code areas and mostly for namespaces or fake.

Comment: Trying to open `the-server` site, I get a 301 redirection to some dodgy-looking all-consonants URL, and Chrome's spam filter (I presume) auto-closes the tab. `example.com` would be a much better choice here - I've just edited that in.

Comment: interesting case. Essentially the wisdom to take away from this is to not mangle your URLs, just put a token like "YOUR_URL_HERE" so it doesn't look like a url at all. I hope that a dodgy url is what caused it instead of the number of namespace urls that are in the content, because otherwise new people are going to have a hard time asking questions about such things as soap or saml...

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you merge that account?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Use `example.com` for made up/fake urls. It is  **specifically** meant to be used in this way and doesn't point to a malicious website.